# In HTML, I don't want to use a lot DIV's, other tags that behave the same?

Tags: html, coding-style, styles

In my textbook I'm reading about HTML and how you shouldn't use a lot of `<div>`'s but starting to use bootstrap, you have to use div's on forms and such.  Is this rule particularly an old one?  What other tags can I use that behave like `<div>`

Comment: How old is the book?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at  this image.
[image]

Source: http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/

Answer (score 0):

Any tag can "behave like div".
Div's are easy to use because they have almost none default styles attached but in real world you can reset any element (for example h1) to look just the same as div.
To avoid divitis just google for semantic elements.
If it's paragraph use `p`, if it's group of fields in `form` you have `fieldset`, maybe it's just a `label`. Don't think how it looks by default because you can change it.

Comment: thanks! i didn't realize they behave the same.  I just figured they were large containers to put into when you have sections in the HTML page you want to wrap

Comment: You should play with css display. You can make inline elements changed to block and vice versa. Resets margins, text styles... Css is about displaying and html about semantics of what you are describing.